# startDrag() not working on listview onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

User can drag a view from the `ListView` to a layout on `onItemLongClick` of `ListView`.Based on some customers feedback I would like to drag the view using `onItemClick` instead of `onItemLongClick`. `startDrag()` is not working while using onitemClick. Please find my code below. What could be the issue ? Same code is working if we are using `onItemLongClick`

```
OnItemClickListener onItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
    {   
        ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new CustomDragShadowBuilder(getActivity());
        view.startDrag(clipData, shadowBuilder,null, 0);
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at:  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

The place you use startDrag is wrong try to use it inside touchlistener. And you can add touch listeners to rows in the adapters' getview Method. A small example i wrote showing the animals image in listview and you can drag and drop these images to container (layout) simply

in Main Activiy

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String TAG="Drag-Drog";

ListView list;
Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_row, imageId);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.container1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

}

public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // do nothing
            Log.d(TAG,"on ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.setBackground(enterShape);
            Log.d(TAG,"on ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setBackground(normalShape);
            Log.d(TAG,"on ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // the view dropped
            // getlocatestate probably gets the reference of this view
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState(); // get the view which
                                                        // will be dropped
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view); // remove the view from the first
                                    // position

            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d(TAG,"on ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.setBackground(normalShape);
            Log.d(TAG,"onACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

In the custom touch listener

public class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

```
public static final String TAG="Drag-Drog";
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // when touch event occurs first check the document
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data=ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        //ClippedData is a complex type containing one or Item instances, 
        //each of which can hold one or more representations of an item of data

        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder=new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder,v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Log.d(TAG,"on Action Down");

        return true;
    } 
    /*
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.)


    */
    else
        return false;

}
```

}

and this is the custom adapter here

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Context context;
private final Integer[] imageId;

public CustomList(Context c, int resource, Integer[] imageId) {

    super(c, resource, imageId);

    this.context = c;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        // we call the view created before to not create a view in each time
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    int imgId = imageId[position];

    viewHolder.img.setImageResource(imgId);

    viewHolder.img.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    ImageView img;

    public ImageView getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(ImageView img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

}
```

}